# Returning Multiple of same result

Tags: php

I am using simple_html_dom to scrape a website currently and everything is being scraped fine but it's displaying the scraped data multiple times.

Here is the selector I am trying to scrape which I think is causing the problems.

```
#wrapper > div.container > div > h3 > a
```

You can view my example [Link Removed].

And my code here is what I am currently using to scrape.

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com/sitefile.php?s=1&page='.$page.'');

foreach($html->find('#wrapper > div.container > div: > h3') as $element) 
{
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo $url = $element->href;

    $html2 = file_get_html($url);

    echo '<br>';    

    $title = $html2->find('#primary > div > div > div > h1',0);
    echo $title = ucwords(strtolower($title->plaintext));

    echo '<br>';

    $youtube = $html2->find('#Playerholder > iframe',0);

    preg_match("/embed\/(.*)\?/", $youtube->src, $output_array);

    echo $youtube = $output_array[1];       
}
```

Comment: Is it maybe because you have `#wrapper > div.container > div: > h3` instead of `#wrapper > div.container > div > h3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue.

So apparently the website you're trying to get content from has two different locations with the same selector that you're scraping for the `#wrapper > div.container > div > h3 > a` which is why it's returning multiple results so try changing this `foreach($html->find('#wrapper > div.container > div: > h3') as $element)` to this `foreach($html->find('.omega-grid > h3 > a') as $element)` and you should have the output you're looking for.

EDIT:

```
foreach($html->find('.omega-grid > h3 > a') as $element) 
{
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo $url = $element->href;

    $html2 = file_get_html($url);

    echo '<br>';    

    $title = $html2->find('#primary > div > div > div > h1',0);
    echo $title = ucwords(strtolower($title->plaintext));

    echo '<br>';

    $youtube = $html2->find('#Playerholder > iframe',0);

    preg_match("/embed\/(.*)\?/", $youtube->src, $output_array);

    echo $youtube = $output_array[1];       
}
```